# How to send back to back http post request without waiting for response in Karate framework

Tags: automation, automated-tests, karate, web-api-testing

I have been writing APT tests in Karate framework and for one of the scenario, I need to do the following

```
Scenario: Testing a POST endpoint with request body

Given url 'http://localhost:8097/user/create'
And request { id: '1234' , name: 'John Smith'}
When method POST
```

At this point 1st request is sent but I dont want to wait for the response and send the 2nd request as shown below

```
Given url 'http://localhost:8097/user/create'
And request { id: '1235' , name: 'Ken Smith'}
When method POST
```

When both the requests are sent, then I wish to wait for response for both of them do the following validations

```
Then status 200
And match $ contains {id:"#notnull"}
```

Could someone help!!

Comment: not directly supported by karate and this is NOT functional testing - there is something called `karate-gatling` look it up. please note you can use Java interop and use Java threads to do what you want. if that is not clear, please assume karate is not the right tool for you